# Como organizar o código PHP e HTML para fazer um e-commerce?

Tags: php, html, e-commerce

Estou fazendo um e-commerce e terminei de fazer o planejamento do site. O site terá que ser feito cadastro antes de se fazer a compra dos produtos, que será feita usando o PayPal.

Minha dúvida é: eu faço as páginas com o login e sem login em HTML e depois coloco o PHP, ou eu faço o PHP e coloco o HTML dentro do PHP?

Comment: A ordem que você vai fazer é irrelevante, apenas faça do jeito em que você possa ir testando conforme vai desenvolvendo.

Comment: Por que não partir de uma base já consolidada, como Magento ?

Comment: PHP "embarca"  o html (e muitas vezes outros conteúdos), então uma página .php suporta conteúdo html naturalmente, veja esta resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18140338/1518921

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leonardo, realmente de fato, a ordem dos fatores não irá alterar o resultado final de seu projeto, porém para melhor visualização e identação de seu código, melhor que seja HTML no PHP quando o PHP predomine no arquivo em questão e vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

Em termos de ordem, a única que deves ter em mente é a própria estrutura. Separar os scripts *PHP* dos *HTML*, e assim por diante.

Deves também ter em mente que os scripts *HTML* serão apenas responsáveis pelo conteúdo estático, se dizes tu que isto se trata de uma loja online, não tem porque forçares o uso de *HTML* e *JS* para tarefas do *PHP*, e do mesmo jeito, não há razões para forçar o *PHP* a gerar grandes quantidades de código  *HTML*, visto que podes usar, e recomendo que uses ficheiros com a extensão `.php`, mesmo que estes sejam responsáveis apenas pelo formulário de login, creio que alguns bytes não vão fazer tanta diferença.

De qualquer das formas não estarias propriamente a organizar o teu código, estarias era a organizar os ficheiros. Para organizar os códigos recomendo que utilizes classes ou simplesmente funções, *por se tratar de uma loja online toda a segurança é pouca*, apenas lembra-te disto.

Se quiseres, e com certeza vais querer aperfeiçoar a estrutura, deves então usar estruturas já prontas, porque além de terem sido programadas por profissionais, já milhares de pessoas as avaliaram, ou então se preferires ir à antiga, vais ter de fazer muito mais esforço do que escolher onde colocar o formulário de login.